# Find rows that contain words that I need

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a BD with almost 1500 rows. Each row has a string of different characters (all within the same cell), in some cases, there are similar words within each row. For example:

```
Row 1: Tempera for children of color red 10 grams 
Row 2: Tempera for adults color black 50 grams 
Row 3: Tempera for children of color yellow 10 grams 
Row 4: Tempera for adults color black 10 grams
```

I am trying to create a macro in which you enter two or more words and that these words are searched in each row, and subsequently, I explain which are the lines that contain the two or more words. For example:

If I entry the words:

- "black tempera" : Rows 2, 4
- "children"      : Rows 1, 3
- "10 tempera"    : Rows 1,3 and 4

Comment: If you have no more than two search criterias, you can use the `AutoFilter` function. Why make a big deal with VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```
Private Function SearchForOneStringInArr(oneString As String, arr() As String) As Boolean
   Dim i
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
       If InStr(1, LCase(oneString), LCase(arr(i))) = 0 Then
            SearchForOneStringInArr = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
SearchForOneStringInArr = True
End Function
Public Function mySearch(rng As Range, toSearch As String) As String
   Dim i As Integer, cell As Range
   i = 1
   Dim strArr() As String
   Dim resultStr As String
   resultStr = "Rows:"
   strArr = Split(toSearch, " ")
   For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If SearchForOneStringInArr(cell.Value, strArr) = True Then
           resultStr = resultStr & Str(i) & " , "
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
    mySearch = resultStr
End Function
```

use the following formula:

```
=mySearch(A1:A4, "black tempera")
=mySearch(A1:A4, "children")
=mySearch(A1:A4, "10 tempera")
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be quite what you're looking for, but one approach rather than writing a macro from scratch would be to use a concatenation function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975471/array-formula-result-concatenated-into-single-cell) with an array formula:-

```
=myconcat(",",IF((1+ISBLANK(B1)-ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,$A$1:$A$4)))*(2-ISBLANK(B1)-ISBLANK(C1))*(1+ISBLANK(C1)-ISERROR(SEARCH(C1,$A$1:$A$4))),ROW($A$1:$A$4),""))
```

where the strings to be searched are in A1:A4 and the words to search on are in B1 and C1.

The formula has to be entered in D1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pulled down.

[image]