# using range in CONCATENATE function

Tags: excel, range, concatenation, libreoffice, calc

I would like to combine the content of many cells in one cell. One possible solution for me is `CONCATENATE` function.

If I use this:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,C1,D1)
```

it works fine, but for:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1:D1)
```

I am seeing such a value: `#VALUE` in the cell. How can I define range in a CONCATENATE function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Excel CONCATENATE function doesn't work for a range or array (it does in Google Sheets).

There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975471/array-formula-result-concatenated-into-single-cell) of a simple UDF that does work with arrays in Excel.