# Extract part of text in Excel with condition

Tags: excel, string, text, split

I know this questions seems redundant but cannot find an answer. I have a text string such as:

A-B-C-D-E-F

I would like to extract only the first 4 items separated by "-". Result should be

A-B-C-D

Alternatively, I am also looking to extract only the 3rd item:

C

I have been trying the MID and SEARCH functions with no success.
Any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I am using V16.60 Office 365 Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel MAC and earlier versions:

Extract first four:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),4))-1)
```

Extract the third:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),2))+1, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),2))-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using TEXTSPLIT (As of this writing only available to Office 365 Insider Beta Channel)

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),1,{1,2,3,4}))
```

Change the `{1,2,3,4}` to `3` for the third.

If one does not have TEXTSPLIT but has TEXTJOIN and is on a PC then:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),1,{1,2,3,4}))
```

Without TEXTJOIN it will require vba. Like this UDF that mimics TEXTJOIN: [MS Excel - Concat with a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165179/ms-excel-concat-with-a-delimiter/42165195#42165195)

Comment: Yup, still learning the new formula.

Comment: Thank you so much @ScottCraner ! Unfortunately, I get an error message #NAME?. Perhaps this is coming from my version of Excel ? I am on Mac V16.60 office 365.

Comment: I also don't seem to have TEXTSPLIT although I do have TEXTJOIN

Comment: That is why neither work.  FILTERXML is not available on MAC and TEXTSPLIT is currently in Beta and only available to Insiders. @AP38.  Hopefully it will be released to all soon.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is what I have ***tried***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),,4))
```

• Formula used in cell **D1**

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,DROP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),,-2))
```

• Formula used in cell **C1**

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),,3))
```

**Note:** Formulas shown above works for **O365 Users, Insiders Beta Channel** users only!

---

However, if you have access to Excel 2019, then you can use either `TEXTJOIN()` or `CONCAT()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell **B9**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT("-"&INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A9,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW(A1:A4))),"-","",1)
```

• Formula used in cell **C9**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT("-"&INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A9,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),3)),"-","",1)
```

---

Since OP has mentioned in comments, that OP is using **O365** in **MAC**, hence here is an update.

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1:D1)*99-98,99)))
```

• Formula used in cell **C1**

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(C1)*99-98,99))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell **D1**

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",100)),200,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to understand (now and in the future) if done in small steps.
Assuming source data is in A2:
in B2: `=FIND("-",$A2)`
in C2: `=FIND("-",$A2,B2+1)`
in D2, E2: copy across from C2
Then in F2: `=LEFT(A2,E2-1)`
You *can* put all of that into one formula, but that's more error-prone.