# Returning column header corresponding to matched value - follow up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet 1

| Name | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| w | 1 |
| e | 1 |
| r | 2 |
| t | 4 |
| y | 6 |
| u | 2 |
| i | NoMatch |
| q | 1 |
| w | 1 |
| e | 1 |
| r | 2 |

Sheet 2

| Name | Male 1 | Female 2 | other 3 | other 4 | other 5 | Donotknow 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| q | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| r | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| e | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| t | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| y | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| u | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I am using this formula in Sheet 1 under Gender:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({1,2,3,4,5,6},MATCH(1,INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$G$9,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9,0),0),0)),"No Match")
```

if I have 2 matches... For example `t`: columns `other 4` and `other 5` have `1`. I would like the output to be `4;5` in the same cell.
How can I modify the formula to reflect that?

I am using an older excel - Filter command does not work.

Comment: Are your sheets really laid out like that?

Comment: You will need vba.  you can use a UDF to replicate TEXTJOIN.  See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165179/ms-excel-concat-with-a-delimiter/42165195#42165195) for an example of that UDF.

Comment: Then you can use `=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$G$9,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9,0),0)=1,{1,2,3,4,5,6},""))`

Comment: @SolarMike yes they are laid out like that. The gender was an example, but the layout is the same. TEXTJOIN worked Scott..

Comment: They look like something now...