# Is it possible to concatenate an array in worksheet formula in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, array-formulas

This:

```
=CONCATENATE({"A","B"})
```

only returns "A". Desired result would be "AB".

This is just an example, I'm interested in using this with results of array formulas but don't know how or if it's even possible.

I'm on Excel 2010

Comment: Try =CONCAT({"A","B"}) instead

Comment: @user11222393 thank you but that formula is unfortunately not available in Excel 2010.

Comment: Depending on the situation, you could use the '&' symbol; e.g. ="A"&"B"

Comment: @gingerox yes but the point is to concatenate an array the number of elements and contents of which I don't know.

Comment: @andrewb not with native formula.  You will need VBA.  You can use the TEXTJOIN UDF noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165179/ms-excel-concat-with-a-delimiter/42165195#42165195 and use `""` as the delimiter.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. I wanted to go without VBA. So it is not possible then :( Oh well.

Comment: Correct in Excel 2010 without dynamic array formula, it is not possible to concatenate a dynamic array.  You would need to use IF statements for each possibility and concatenate those, but that will get unruly if you have a large number of data points to test.