# Excel column A same value and column B value combine in Column D

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Please help looking for the excel formula:
The column A have the same value, column B is qty, combine in text with '+' in column D, the column C is a,b,c, sample picture below, the Column D is in text.

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in the output! But concatenating in this way it only increases your responsibility of splitting them later for further calculations with numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an easy feat using a simple DAX measure.

There should be a build-in add-on called `Power Pivot` for you in ms ***Excel 2016***. If you haven't already enabled it then have a look [here](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/enabling-power-pivot-excel-2016/). Power Pivot allows us to:

- Select your data (including headers);
- Click 'Add to Data Model' on the 'Power Pivot' tab. A pop-up should appear, you can close this for now;
- Under the same 'Power Pivot' tab, now click 'Measures'>'New Measure';
- Select the right table and give the measure a name that makes sense, for example 'TEXTJOIN';
- In the formula box apply the following formula: `=CONCATENATEX(Table1,[Qty],"+")`. Apply the appropriate tablename before clicking 'OK';
- In the same tab, now click 'Manage' and under the 'Home' tab in the pop-up window click 'PivotTable';
- Choose where to output the new table, drag 'Items' to rows and the measure you just created to values.

The output then, should look like:

[image]

**Note**: I removed 'Grand Totals'.

Comment: Nice trick using DAX measure!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:B7,
     _items, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _uniqi, UNIQUE(_items),
     HSTACK(_uniqi, BYROW(_uniqi, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN("+",1,IF(x=_items,TAKE(_data,,-1),""))))))
```

---

Or, Use `GROUPBY()` function:

```
=LET(
     x, GROUPBY(A2:A7,B2:B7,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0),
     HSTACK(TAKE(x,,1), SUBSTITUTE(TAKE(x,,-1),", ","+")))
```

---

Alternative way of writing the above function as mentioned by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir. Simple & shorter version.

```
=GROUPBY(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("+",,x)),0,0)
```

---

- Using `LET()` function it becomes easier to read and define variables which can be used to avoid repeats of formulas.
- `_items` using `TAKE()` function get the first range from `_data` variable.
- Using `UNIQUE()` function extract the unique values from above.
- Using `BYROW()` to run a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to join using `TEXTJOIN()` function with a delimiter `+` after checking whether `x` is equal to `_items` else return empty.
- Lastly, using `HSTACK()` combine both the arrays.

---

As per OP's comments:

> *Sorry, my ms office excel is ms office 2016 and it do not have the*
> *'let' formula...*

---

And this can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Items", type text}, {"Qty", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Items"}, {{"TextValue", each Text.Combine([Qty],"+"), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Also as per `MSFT` **[Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2)** - `Excel 2016` supports
`CONCAT()` function that said then one can use the following:

[image]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT("+"&IF(D2=A$2:A$7,B$2:B$7,"-")),"+-",),"+",,1)
```

---

Comment: Sorry, my ms office excel is ms office 2016 and it do not have the 'let' formula...

Comment: Use `Power Query` then, it will be more flexible.

Comment: Food for thought; but the `GROUPBY()` option could be written like `=GROUPBY(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("+",,x)),0,0)`

Comment: Worked now may be i was doing something wrong! Great Suggestions @JvdV Sir!

Answer (score 1):

I admire [Mayukh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya)'s knowledge about recent Excel features, but I prefer a more "old-fashioned" approach, based on the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("+";TRUE;IF(A$2:A$8=C2;B$2:B$8;""))
```

This is what it looks like in a screenshot:

[image]

I started working with the formula `IF(A$2:A$8=C2;B$2:B$8;"")`, I saw this created a sequence and I decided to fit it into a `TextJoin()` function.

Beware: the `IF()`-clause contains an empty string in the `ELSE`-case, which is skipped, using the `TRUE` as the second parameter of the `TextJoin()` function.

**Edit: what about TextJoin()?**
As stated by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv), Excel 2016 does not support `TextJoin()` function, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165179/ms-excel-concat-with-a-delimiter/42165195#42165195) contains a VBA UDF (User-Defined Function) `TextJoin()`.

Comment: Please do note OP is working in ms Excel 2016 =)

Comment: @JvdV: Exactly my point: having access to all those new features and yet being able to solve a problem using grey-haired troglodyte functions, great! :-)

Comment: Not sure what you are refering to, but `TEXTJOIN()` is Excel 2019 and above.

Comment: Oh, sorry. On my PC, I have `TextJoin()` function already a long time. Other functions (like `ToCol()`) have been added just recently. Hence my (apparently wrong) idea that `TextJoin()` is some old function.

Comment: I see, honest mistake! I was allready thinking maybe you had a UDF named `TEXTJOIN()` you were refering to like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165195/97581940) one.

Comment: @JvdV: good catch. I've updated my answer accordingly.