# Pulling data from another excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file. Sheet one contains a column titled hello function starting from A1. Sheet2 also contains a column titled hello functions but it is in O1, In A1 of sheet2 contains a column titled business applications which corresponds to the hello function column. I want a function in sheet1 that reads A1's hello function name and uses sheet2' information to fill the cell with the respective business applications that are in sheet2. Sometimes there are multiple business applications for 1 function, but i want them all organised in one cell, separated by commas. Im using excel 2016

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(Sheet2!$O$2:$O$491=A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$491, ""))
```

I just get error #Name?

Comment: `Excel 2016` dont support [TEXTJOIN()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) look into using [CONCAT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2)

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IF((Sheet2!$O$2:$O$491=A2)*(Sheet2!$O$2:$O$491<>""),", "&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$491,"")),", ",,1)` not tested since there is no sample data, perhaps could try the above. also it needs to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I thought CONCAT and TEXTJOIN came out at the same time.  CONCATENATE has been around forever but not CONCAT

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, yes but both were in preview mode however if one is using a valid license of `Excel` can use `CONCAT()` in `Excel 2016` as per `MSFT` Even i have used it. not in the year `2016` but 4 years later in `2020`

Comment: Interesting that they retroactively added CONCAT but not TEXTJOIN to 2016. @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: @nothing  here is vba to use as a UDF that mimics TEXTJOIN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165179/ms-excel-concat-with-a-delimiter/42165195#42165195

Comment: Thanks, i seem to be getting the same #Name? Error with ur function too

Comment: Then don't think you are using a subscription version of `Excel`. There are lot of freebies for `10 USD` `Excel 2016` try to get a valid one from `MSFT`

Comment: or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843881/textjoin-udf-for-excel-2013/45845229#45845229

Comment: I definitely am. This is my uni computers

Comment: Sorry I am not sure where you are in `university` or using an `enterprise` version i just said, what i know and used personally. Also `university` are volume licensed may differ the build versions. check with your `IT` of `uni`

Comment: Also if its not working, then use as already suggested by @ScottCraner Sir. with `VBA` + `UDF` can find the links on right hand side. I have used the posted by Sir in the first link, it works everytime btw.